# Is there any way remove whitespaces end of lines from multiple line string?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I couldn't figure out how to remove trailing spaces from a multiline string using just regex without using any loop statements. Could you help me?

```
commentSymbols.ToList().ForEach(t =>
    {
        text = Regex.Replace(text, t + ".+", "").Trim();
    });

    return text;
```

I handled the values ​​from the parameter as a string array with Regex in the foreach loop. But left a space at the end of the first line(returned value -> 'apples, pears '). I don't know much about regex.

Comment: I found the answer.  text = Regex.Replace(text, @"\s*(\n)", "$1"); I added this code blog and it got resolved.

Comment: You should be able to post this as an answer even to your own question (it's actually encouraged).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.
`text = Regex.Replace(text, @"\s*(\n)", "$1");`
I added this code blog and it got resolved.